# write a system of linear equations that has $U$ (subspace) as the set of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

given $U$ a subspace generated by the vectors $v_1=(0,1,2,3),v_2=(1,0,-3,1),v_3=(-3,1,11,0)$

1) **find a basis of $U$**

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2&3 \\ 
1&0&-3&1 \\ 
-3&1&11&0 
 \\
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-3&1 \\ 
0&1&2&3 \\ 
0&1&2&3
 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-3&1 \\ 
0 &1&2&3\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

So two vectors are linear independent.

a base of $U$ is $\{(0,1,2,3),(1,0,-3,1)\}$

2) **write a system of linear equations that has $U$ as the set of solutions.**

The problem is this question,I don't know where to start. What I can say is that this system of equation cannot be "full rank" because if the matrix associated with the system has max rank that means **one unique solution**, which is not what is asked. Somehow I need to find infinite solutions such that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}y+2z+3t=0\\x-3z+t=0\end{array}\right.$$Now, get two linearly independent solutions of the system. Say, for instance, that you take $(3,-2,1,0)$ and $(-1,-3,0,1)$. Now, take the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}3x-2y+z=0\\-x-3y+t=0\end{array}\right.$$(the coefficients are the coordinates of the solutions). And… it's done!

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$U=\{a(0,1,2,3)+b(1,0,-3,1)\; |\; a,b\in \Bbb K\}=\{(b,a,2a-3b,3a+b)\; |\; a,b\in\Bbb K\}=\{(x,y,z,t)\in\Bbb K^4\; |\; \begin{cases} z=2y-3x\\ t=3y+x\end{cases}\}= \{(x,y,z,t)\in\Bbb K^4\; |\; \begin{cases} 2y-3x-z=0\\ 3y+x-t=0\end{cases}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Write that the matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2&3 \\ 
1&0&-3&1 \\ 
-3&1&11&0 \\
x&y&z&t \\
\end{bmatrix}\quad \text{or }\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-3&1 \\ 
0 &1&2&3\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
x&y&z&t
\end{bmatrix}$$
has rank $2$, in terms of  minor subdeterminants